# How to incrementally write data to hive table from Kafka with insert/delete support?

Tags: hive, apache-kafka

I have a use-case where I need to write data from Kafka to Hive incrementally with insert/delete operations support.

I am currently exploring the following options but didn't find delete operation support while writing data from Kafka to hive:

1. [Flafka [Flume + Kafka]](https://blog.cloudera.com/flafka-apache-flume-meets-apache-kafka-for-event-processing/)
2. [kafka-connect-hdfs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html):

Comment: After exploring please update your question with details.

Comment: @cypher_neo welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you update your question with … well… a question? :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I want to know whether I can perform a delete operation on a hive table while writing data from Kafka to Hive? I hope this clarifies my question.